# How to keep spatial information after raster processing of satellite data in r

Tags: raster, r, coordinates, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff

In R raster package i write an image in tiff format after certain raster processing but the spatial information is missing of new image. That's why i have to geo-reference the image again. How this can be avoided?
For example, i want to get relative normalization image of landsat data. The code is

```
library(landsat)
library(raster)
library(lmodel2)
library(rgdal)
a<-raster("D:/Paper/test/1997-137-b3.tif")
x<-as.matrix(a)
b<-raster("D:/Paper/test/2007-137-b3.tif")
y<-as.matrix(b)
z<-relnorm(master = x, tofix = y, nperm=100, method="MA")
RMA was not requested: it will not be computed.

image(z$newimage)
m<-raster(z$newimage)
writeRaster(m, filename="D:/Paper/test/2007-b3-rd.tif", format="GTiff", options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
```

But after processing the file i write in raster format missing spatial information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Set up a new "empty" raster inheriting the geo-information from `a`
m<-raster(a) 

# Set the values of the new raster
setValues(m, z$newimage)

writeRaster(m, filename="D:/Paper/test/2007-b3-rd.tif", format="GTiff", options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting your raster objects into a matrix, you have to convert them into a "SpatialGridDataFrame" (sp package) to keep their spatial information.

I encountered a similar issue with the relnorm-function and could solve it this way. (See here: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303516/relative-radiometric-normalization-of-multisensor-landsat-level-2-images-using-r/303607#303607))

In this case, the following code should work:

```
    library(landsat)
    library(raster)
    library(lmodel2)
    library(rgdal)
    library(sp)
    a<-raster("D:/Paper/test/1997-137-b3.tif")
    x<-as(a, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
    b<-raster("D:/Paper/test/2007-137-b3.tif")
    y<-as(b, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
    z<-relnorm(master = x, tofix = y, nperm=100, method="MA")
    RMA was not requested: it will not be computed.

    m<-as(z$newimage, "RasterBrick")
    writeRaster(m, filename="D:/Paper/test/2007-b3-rd.tif", format="GTiff", options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
```