# Relative Radiometric Normalization of multisensor Landsat Level 2 images using R

Tags: r, landsat, digital-image-processing, time-series, normalize

For my time series analysis, i need to use images of the three Landsat sensors (TM, ETM+ and OLI). I chose the already atmospheric corrected surface reflectance/Level-2 products. Due to the radiometric differences between the sensors, i still have to normalize them (i think) as a pre-processing step.

When i wanted to do this in R using a regression method via the relnorm-Function (landsat-package), i got the following Error Code despite the images having exactly the same values for dimensions and extent:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

I use the following code to clip and normalize identical bands of the TM-product of different dates. The images don't contain any clouds, thus no mask is used:

```
library(landsat)
library(lmodel2)
library(RStoolbox)
library(raster)

ma <- raster("D:/Working_Directory/LT05_L1TP_144051_20041216_20161127_01_T1_sr_band1.tif")

to <- raster("D:/Working_Directory/LE07_L1TP_144051_19991109_20170216_01_T1_sr_band1.tif")

shp <- readOGR("D:/Working_Directory/transect.shp")

#Clipping both bands:
clipped_ma <- crop(ma, extent(shp))
clipped_ma <- mask(clipped_ma, shp)
clipped_to <- crop(to, extent(shp))
clipped_to <- mask(clipped_to, shp)

#Trying to use the relnorm-function (no mask, OLS-method):
normalized <- relnorm(master=clipped_ma, tofix=clipped_to, method = "OLS", nperm = 0)
```

What is wrong with the code or the data(-format), that is causing the aforementioned Error?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer by Spacedman is correct in pointing out that a wrong format (raster) of the input-objects (master- and tofix-image) caused the Error Message mentioned in the question.

Instead of converting the objects into a matrix however, it is better for pre-processing in GIS-applications to convert the input-files (.tif) into "SpatialGridDataFrames" (sp-package) to keep the spatial information and still be able to run the relnorm-function. 
After that, the output-image "$newimage" can be converted back into the raster format and be saved via writeRaster-function or kept loaded in the memory to later stack it with further output-files.

Here the final code (for one band):

```
library(landsat)
library(lmodel2)
library(RStoolbox)
library(raster)
library(sp)

#Loading the input-images and the shapefile for clipping/subsetting:
ma <- raster("D:/Working_Directory/LT05_L1TP_144051_20041216_20161127_01_T1_sr_band1.tif")

to <- raster("D:/Working_Directory/LE07_L1TP_144051_19991109_20170216_01_T1_sr_band1.tif")

shp <- readOGR("D:/Working_Directory/transect.shp")

#Clipping both bands:
clipped_ma <- crop(ma, extent(shp))
clipped_ma <- mask(clipped_ma, shp)
clipped_to <- crop(to, extent(shp))
clipped_to <- mask(clipped_to, shp)

#Converting into "SpatialGridDataFrames":
ma_grid <- as(clipped_image, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
to_grid <- as(clipped_image2, "SpatialGridDataFrame")

#Running relnorm-function (no mask, OLS-method):
normalized <- relnorm(master=clipped_ma, tofix=clipped_to, method = "OLS", nperm = 0)

#Converting back the output-image as raster class:
normalized_image <- normalized[["newimage"]]
normalized_raster <- as(normalized_image, "RasterBrick")

#Saving as raster file (.tif):
writeRaster(normalized_raster, choose.files(default = "", caption = "Save as rasterfile",
                                    multi = TRUE, filters = Filters,
                                    index = nrow(Filters)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the help for `relnorm`:

```
Arguments:

  master: The target image, in SpatialGridDataFrame, data frame, matrix
          or vector format.
```

That does not include a `raster` object.

This duplicates your error:

```
> r = raster(matrix(runif(16),4,4))
> s = raster(matrix(runif(16),4,4))
> relnorm(r,s)
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

and conversion to matrix fixes it:

```
> relnorm(matrix(r),matrix(s))
RMA was not requested: it will not be computed.

$regression.results
  Method  Intercept    Slope Angle (degrees) P-perm (1-tailed)
[etc etc]
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my issue and i can run the relnorm-function. However, i now face the problem that i can't make the conversion of the output file ($newimage) back to a raster file with the same spatial information as the input file ("clipped_to"). I tried the solution offered here: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244128/how-to-keep-spatial-information-after-raster-processing-of-satellite-data-in-r) But this returns another Error code: `Error in setValues(ma, normalized$newimage) : 
  length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1`